# how can i make the class Forum work with strings in c++?

Tags: c++

Hello i i get [Error] no matching function for call to 'Forum::Forum(const char [5], const char [7], int, int, int, const char [6], const char [6], int, const char [6])' at

Forum f1=Forum("info","kostas",2005,2,220,"info1","nikos",2006,"hello");

!!! I am new in object oriented programming so i don't know how to use string! What happens here?? Thank you very much!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Post{

    int postNumber;
    string title;
    string creator;
    int dateOfCreation;
    string text;

    public:
        Post(int p=1,string t="first",string c="kostas",int da=2012, string te="text"){

            postNumber=p;
            title=t;
            creator=c;
            dateOfCreation=da;
            text=te;

            cout<<"I just created a post with"<<"Post number: "<<postNumber<<' '<<"Title: "<<title
            <<title<<"with the name of creator: "<<creator<<"and date of creation: "<<dateOfCreation
            <<text<<endl;

        }
        ~Post(){
            cout<<"Post number"<<postNumber<<"is about to be destroyed"<<endl;
        }

        void print(){
            cout<<postNumber<<' '<<title<<' '<<creator<<' '<<dateOfCreation<<' '<<text<<endl;

        }

};

class Thread{
    std::string thema;
    std::string creator;
    int dateOfCreation;
    int numberOfPost;

    public:
        Thread(string t="xrhisimes plhrofories",string c="kostas",int d=2015,int n=0){

            thema=t;
            creator=c;
            dateOfCreation=d;
            numberOfPost=n;

            cout<<"I just created a Threat with"<<"thema: "<<thema<<' '
            <<"name of creator: "<<creator<<' '<<"date of creation: "<<dateOfCreation<<' '
            <<"and with number of post: "<<numberOfPost<<endl;
        }
        ~Thread(){
            cout<<"Theat with subject: "<<thema<<"is about to be destroyed "<<endl;
        }

        void print(){
            cout<<thema<<' '<<creator<<' '<<dateOfCreation<<' '<<numberOfPost<<endl;
        }

};

class Forum{
    Post*post;
    Thread*thread;
    std::string subject;

    public:
        Forum(string s="antikeimenostrafis programmatismos"){
            subject=s;
            cout<<"Forum was just created with subject: "<<subject<<endl;
            post=new Post;
            thread= new Thread;

            post->print();
            thread->print();
        }
        Forum(string s,string th,string c,int d, int n,
        int p, string t, string cr, int da, string te){

            cout<<"Forum was just created with subject: "<<subject<<'\n'<<endl;

            post=new Post(p,t,cr,da,te);
            thread=new Thread(th,c,d,n);

            post->print();
            thread->print();
        }
};

int main(){
    Forum f1=Forum("info","kostas",2005,2,220,"info1","nikos",2006,"hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Use descriptive identifiers for your variables.. `t`, for example, contains no information about what the variable represents and how it should be used. This makes the code harder to read and thus debug and maintain. Time spent making your code descriptive saves time later.

Comment: Thank Everyone for your quick answer!Your help was so helpful

Answer (score 3):

Your `Forum` constructor doesn't match what you're trying to give it. 2 `strings`, then `ints`, whereas the constructor takes 3 `strings`.

```
Forum(string s,string th,string c...
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply because you're missing a string parameter in that function call. 
`Forum f1=Forum("info","kostas", <string missing here>, 2005,2,220,"info1","nikos",2006,"hello");`

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot!! ha ha ha ! You the best!